# Diferenciar CPF e CNPJ que estão nas mesma coluna de banco de dados MySQL

Tags: python-2.7

Olá,

Procurei em vários sites e não encontrei, por isso decidi perguntar aqui. Tenho uma tabela de banco de dados relacional, MySQL, que possui uma única coluna tanto pra CPF quanto pra CNPJ. Além disso, essa coluna está no formato bigint, ou seja, os zeros a esquerda são suprimidos. Preciso pegar apenas os CPFs. Bastaria utilizar o validador de CPF certo? Porém, percebi que há registros que possuem menos de 11 digitos e passam na validação tanto de CPF quanto de CNPJ. Sendo assim, alguém sabe alguma outra validação que me permita diferenciar de fato, um CPF de um CNPJ? Seguem os códigos que estou utilizando pra fazer validação de CPF e de CNPJ e seguem exemplos de registros que passam em ambas validações: 980258480, 343522950 e 937439126.

```
def isCPFValido(cpf, d1=0, d2=0, i=0):
    if cpf is not None:
        if len(cpf) > 11:
            return False
        while i < 10:
            d1, d2, i = (d1 + (int(cpf[i]) * (11 - i - 1))) % 11 if i < 9 else d1, (
            d2 + (int(cpf[i]) * (11 - i))) % 11, i + 1
        return (int(cpf[9]) == (11 - d1 if d1 > 1 else 0)) and (int(cpf[10]) == (11 - d2 if d2 > 1 else 0))
    else:
        return False


def validar_cnpj(cnpj):
  if not isinstance(cnpj, basestring):
    cnpj = str(cnpj)
  cnpj = format_cnpj(cnpj)
  cnpj = ''.join(re.findall('\d', cnpj))
  if (not cnpj) or (len(cnpj) < 14):
    return False
  # Pega apenas os 12 primeiros dígitos do CNPJ e gera os 2 dígitos que faltam
  inteiros = map(int, cnpj)
  novo = inteiros[:12]
  prod = [5, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
  while len(novo) < 14:
    r = sum([x*y for (x, y) in zip(novo, prod)]) % 11
    if r > 1:
      f = 11 - r
    else:
      f = 0
    novo.append(f)
    prod.insert(0, 6)
  # Se o número gerado coincidir com o número original, é válido
  if novo == inteiros:
    return cnpj
  return False
```

Comment: se voce selecionasse os valores na coluna que forem > 11 dgtos, esses com certeza são CNPJ, isola eles e valida, seleciona todos os que que forem <= 11, isola eles e valida, os que sobrarem, voce precisa verificar porque para uma requisição

Comment: (F* Enter, grrr...)quiz dizer, para uma requisição mais precisa dos valores dessa coluna, eles vão necessariamente ter de estarem corretos no mundo real, para isolar eles, voce pode selecionar os campos como texto e validar seu comprimento, sendo > 11, temos os CNPJs e por ai vai, par os que forem < 11, voce vai ter de redigitar mesmo no caso da necessidade deles de fato.

Comment: jah tive um caso parecido com isso ha tempos atras, tive de fazer isso para separar e por coincidencia também tinha vários números com comprimento < 11, 'deo um BO lascado', rerere, quando precisou desses números

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Você pode usar o brazilnum

```
from brazilnum.cnpj import validate_cnpj
from brazilnum.cpf import validate_cpf

# Retorna True se for um CNPJ válido
validate_cnpj(documento)

# Retorna True se for um CPF válido
validate_cpf(documento)
```

Espero ter ajudado.